# Installing CPAN modules fails

Tags: c#, perl, cpan

I try to install CPAN Modules using the cpan.exe.

When I try to install a module with "install XML::DOM" fails stating dmake.exe is NOT OK,

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\ehsan\Documents>cpan
Set up gcc environment - gcc.exe (release with patches / build 20130526 by st
berryperl.com) 4.7.3

There seems to be running another CPAN process (pid 5932).  Contacting...
Other job not responding. Shall I overwrite the lockfile 'C:\Perl\cpan\.lock'
Y/n) [y] y

cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v1.9800)
Enter 'h' for help.


cpan> install XML::DOM
Reading 'C:\Perl\cpan\Metadata'
  Database was generated on Thu, 24 Oct 2013 11:09:28 GMT
Running install for module 'XML::DOM'
Running make for T/TJ/TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.44.tar.gz
Checksum for C:\Perl\cpan\sources\authors\id\T\TJ\TJMATHER\XML-DOM-1.44.tar.g
k
Scanning cache C:\Perl/cpan/build for sizes
............................................................................D

XML-DOM-1.44/
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/DocumentType.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/DocumentFragment.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/AttlistDecl.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/Notation.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/Attr.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/ProcessingInstruction.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/Entity.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/Document.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/Parser.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/NodeList.pm
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/Node.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/ElementDecl.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/EntityReference.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/NodeList.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/CharacterData.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/DOMException.pm
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/PerlSAX.pm
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/NamedNodeMap.pm
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/NamedNodeMap.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/Comment.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/Element.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/XMLDecl.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/CDATASection.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/DOMImplementation.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/Text.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/AttDef.pod
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM.pm
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/Handler/
XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/Handler/BuildDOM.pm
XML-DOM-1.44/t/
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_jp_minus.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_noexpand.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_template.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_jp_cdata.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_jp_modify.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_text.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_cdata.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_jp_attr.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_extent.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_minus.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_attr.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_encode.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_jp_example.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_extent.ent
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_jp_print.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_documenttype.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_extent.dtd
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_jp_astress.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/build_dom.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_print.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_astress.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_modify.t
XML-DOM-1.44/t/dom_example.t
XML-DOM-1.44/FAQ.xml
XML-DOM-1.44/Changes
XML-DOM-1.44/MANIFEST
XML-DOM-1.44/META.yml
XML-DOM-1.44/CmpDOM.pm
XML-DOM-1.44/samples/
XML-DOM-1.44/samples/minutes.xml
XML-DOM-1.44/samples/REC-xml-19980210.xml
XML-DOM-1.44/BUGS
XML-DOM-1.44/CheckAncestors.pm
XML-DOM-1.44/XML-Parser-2.31.patch
XML-DOM-1.44/Makefile.PL
XML-DOM-1.44/README

  CPAN.pm: Building T/TJ/TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.44.tar.gz

Set up gcc environment - gcc.exe (release with patches / build 20130526 by st
berryperl.com) 4.7.3
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite XML::Parser::PerlSAX 0.07 not found.
Warning: prerequisite XML::RegExp 0 not found.
Writing Makefile for XML-DOM
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----       TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.44.tar.gz       ----
    XML::Parser::PerlSAX [requires]
    XML::RegExp [requires]
Running make test
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running make install
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running install for module 'XML::Parser::PerlSAX'
Running make for K/KM/KMACLEOD/libxml-perl-0.08.tar.gz
Checksum for C:\Perl\cpan\sources\authors\id\K\KM\KMACLEOD\libxml-perl-0.08.t
gz ok
libxml-perl-0.08/
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/Handler/
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/Handler/Subs.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/Handler/CanonXMLWriter.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/Handler/Sample.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/Handler/XMLWriter.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/PatAct/
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/PatAct/ActionTempl.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/PatAct/PatternTempl.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/PatAct/Amsterdam.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/PatAct/MatchName.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/PatAct/ToObjects.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/SAX2Perl.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/Perl2SAX.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/ESISParser.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/Parser/
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/XML/Parser/PerlSAX.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/Data/
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/Data/Grove/
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/Data/Grove/Parent.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/Data/Grove/Visitor.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/lib/Data/Grove.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/CreatingPatActModules.pod
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/interface-style.pod
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/modules.xml
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/sax-2.0-adv.html
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/UsingPatActModules.pod
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/PerlSAX.pod
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/mirror.sh
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/sax-2.0.html
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/UsingPerlSAX.pod
libxml-perl-0.08/doc/index.html
libxml-perl-0.08/Changes
libxml-perl-0.08/MANIFEST
libxml-perl-0.08/examples/
libxml-perl-0.08/examples/schema.xml
libxml-perl-0.08/examples/MyHandler.pm
libxml-perl-0.08/examples/myhandler.xml
libxml-perl-0.08/examples/myhandler.pl
libxml-perl-0.08/examples/schema.pl
libxml-perl-0.08/examples/perlsax-test.pl
libxml-perl-0.08/examples/esis-test.pl
libxml-perl-0.08/t/
libxml-perl-0.08/t/schema.t
libxml-perl-0.08/t/stream.t
libxml-perl-0.08/t/xp_sax.t
libxml-perl-0.08/t/subs.t
libxml-perl-0.08/t/canon_xml_writer.t
libxml-perl-0.08/t/amsterdam.t
libxml-perl-0.08/ChangeLog
libxml-perl-0.08/libxml-perl.spec
libxml-perl-0.08/libxml-perl-0.08.spec
libxml-perl-0.08/Makefile.PL
libxml-perl-0.08/README

  CPAN.pm: Building K/KM/KMACLEOD/libxml-perl-0.08.tar.gz

Set up gcc environment - gcc.exe (release with patches / build 20130526 by st
berryperl.com) 4.7.3
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for libxml-perl
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
CreateProcess failed (2).
dmake.exe:  Error executing 'C:\PROGRA~1\RATIONAL\RATION~1\NUTCROOT\mksnt\sh.
 -c C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe -MExtUtils::Command -e mkpath -- blib\lib': No such
e or directory
dmake.exe:  Error code -1, while making 'blib\lib\.exists'
  KMACLEOD/libxml-perl-0.08.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Running install for module 'XML::RegExp'
Running make for T/TJ/TJMATHER/XML-RegExp-0.04.tar.gz
Checksum for C:\Perl\cpan\sources\authors\id\T\TJ\TJMATHER\XML-RegExp-0.04.ta
z ok
XML-RegExp-0.04/
XML-RegExp-0.04/META.yml
XML-RegExp-0.04/test.pl
XML-RegExp-0.04/README
XML-RegExp-0.04/Changes
XML-RegExp-0.04/MANIFEST
XML-RegExp-0.04/lib/
XML-RegExp-0.04/lib/XML/
XML-RegExp-0.04/lib/XML/RegExp.pm
XML-RegExp-0.04/Makefile.PL

  CPAN.pm: Building T/TJ/TJMATHER/XML-RegExp-0.04.tar.gz

Set up gcc environment - gcc.exe (release with patches / build 20130526 by st
berryperl.com) 4.7.3
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for XML::RegExp
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
CreateProcess failed (2).
dmake.exe:  Error executing 'C:\PROGRA~1\RATIONAL\RATION~1\NUTCROOT\mksnt\sh.
 -c C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe -MExtUtils::Command -e mkpath -- blib\lib\XML': No s
 file or directory
dmake.exe:  Error code -1, while making 'blib\lib\XML\.exists'
  TJMATHER/XML-RegExp-0.04.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Running make for T/TJ/TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.44.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory C:\Perl\cpan\build\XML-DOM-1.44-P
El

  CPAN.pm: Building T/TJ/TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.44.tar.gz

Warning: Prerequisite 'XML::Parser::PerlSAX => 0.07' for 'TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.
tar.gz' failed when processing 'KMACLEOD/libxml-perl-0.08.tar.gz' with 'make
NO'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
Warning: Prerequisite 'XML::RegExp => 0' for 'TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.44.tar.gz' f
ed when processing 'TJMATHER/XML-RegExp-0.04.tar.gz' with 'make => NO'. Conti
ng, but chances to succeed are limited.
CreateProcess failed (2).
dmake.exe:  Error executing 'C:\PROGRA~1\RATIONAL\RATION~1\NUTCROOT\mksnt\sh.
 -c C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe -MExtUtils::Command -e mkpath -- blib\lib': No such
e or directory
dmake.exe:  Error code -1, while making 'blib\lib\.exists'
  TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.44.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Failed during this command:
 KMACLEOD/libxml-perl-0.08.tar.gz             : make NO
 TJMATHER/XML-DOM-1.44.tar.gz                 : make NO
 TJMATHER/XML-RegExp-0.04.tar.gz              : make NO


cpan>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the complete output you will see that there is further information about the error given.

```
dmake.exe:  Error executing 'C:\PROGRA~1\RATIONAL\RATION~1\NUTCROOT\mksnt\sh.
 -c C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe -MExtUtils::Command -e mkpath -- blib\lib': No such
e or directory
```

So it seems that either the path "C:\PROGRA~1\RATIONAL\RATION~1\NUTCROOT\mksnt\sh."  or "C:\Perl\bin\" does not exist.

Comment: so can i create the directory ?if yes what is that RATION~1\?

Comment: Well only creating will for sure not be enough. It seems that there has to be some tool from Rational installed. At least it is stated in the script file you are using. Can you open the cmd and try to execute dmake.exe just to ensure that you have dmake installed correctly.

Comment: As i don't have your computer at hand i can only suggest you to check the paths and check if the tools are installed correctly. Sorry for that.

Comment: No sorry i can't do that.